# Did Muhammad (saw) ever recite the entire Quran in front of the sahaba?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, quran-recitation, sahaba

I read that during every Ramadan, Muhammad (s.a.w.) would recite the entire Quran to Jibreel. But did Muhammad (s.a.w.) do this privately with Jibreel? Or were the sahaba present at the scene? Did they hear Muhammad (s.a.w.) recite the entire Quran every Ramadan in front of Jibreel?

Comment: This is not how it worked or works now if somebody wants to become a hafidh. Our Prophet used to recite new Verses and his sahab used to repeat them. Our prophet was tested by Jibreel and he tested the sahaba who were memorizing. There's no use in hearing him recite the entire Quran (at once), as they won't be (at least this sounds unbelievable) able to memorize this lot of "information".

Answer (score 2):

`The word entire must be the word responsible for not attracting any answers (maybe in fear of down-votes also). But excluding the word entire, the answer is obvious.`

---

Prophet PBUH used to recite the *Quran* infront of the *Sahaba* R. And these recitings includes very long recitings. Such as

- we know a well-known [hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38960) in Sahih Muslim where the *tahajjud* salah of our beloved Prophet PBUH was described by Hudhayfah ibn Al-Yaman R., where he recited nearly 5 juz before going for *rukoo*. `[5 juz is equivalent to 1/6th of the Quran]`
- Also during the *Fazr* congregations the *Sahaba* R. had the chance to hear recitations for longer periods. `[It is Sunnah to recite for longer periods during the Farz salah of the Fazr prayers.]`

**All of these clearly indicate that the *sahaba* R. had a plenty of opportunity to hear longer recitations of the Quran from the Prophet PBUH.**

- The Prophet PBUH himself along with other *sahaba* used to teach the Quran to the new Muslims who came to Madina.
- Also there are quite a number of *sahaba* R. (`huffaz`) who memorized the whole Quran at the Prophet's PBUH lifetime. Such as the *Sahaba* R. who used to reside in the *suffa* of the *Al-Masjid an-Nabawi*.
- The *Sahaba* R. (`katebeen`) who had the role of writing the verses, all of them were `hafiz`.

**So it is likely that during their memorization efforts, they have recited the Quran infront of the Prophet PBUH, it is likely that the Prophet PBUH have also recited different *Sura*s infront of them. `If anyone have seen the memorizing of the Quran by the students who are trying to hefz, s/he will have a better understanding of the intense recitings done by them and their teachers.`**

- Sometimes the Prophet PBUH solely recited the Quran infront of the *sahaba* R. Say for example,

  > Narrated Anas bin Malik: 
  >   The Prophet said to Ubai (bin Ka'b). "Allah has ordered me to recite to you:--'Those who disbelieve among the people of the Scripture and among the idolators are not going to stop (from their disbelief.') (Sura 98) Ubai said, "Did Allah mention me by name?" The Prophet said, "Yes." On that, Ubai wept. 
  >   `Bukhari :: Book 6 :: Volume 60 :: Hadith 483`

---

It is evident that reciting for longer periods of time and reciting to each other was a common practice of the Prophet PBUH and the Sahaba R.

But to comment on the exact question that whether the Prophet PBUH have recited the entire Quran infront of a **single person** needs extensive and elaborate research.