# Reference of a hadith about the night prayer of The Prophet pbuh

Tags: source-identification, reference-request

I needed the reference of a hadith to complete [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38544) answer.

Many of us have heard of a well-known hadith where the tahajjud salah of our beloved Prophet PBUH was described by a sahaba, where he recited nearly 5 juz before going for rukoo.

I cannot remember the name of that Sahaba R. and the exact hadith. I needed the reference of that hadith.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are referring to the companion [Hudhayfah ibn Al-Yaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudhayfah_ibn_al-Yaman), who narrated this [hadith](http://www.sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/102) in Sahih Muslim:

> عن أبي عبد الله حذيفة بن اليمان رضي الله عنهما قال‏:‏ صليت مع النبي
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم ذات ليلة فافتتح البقرة فقلت يركع عند المائة ثم مضى.
>   فقلت يصلي بها في ركعة، فمضى. فقلت يركع بها، ثم افتتح النساء. فقرأها ثم
>   افتتح آل عمران فقرأها يقرأ مترسلاً إذا مر بآية فيها تسبيح سبح وإذا مر
>   بسؤال سأل وإذا مر بتعوذ تعوذ. ثم ركع فجعل يقول‏: سبحان ربي العظيم‏.
>   فكان ركوعه نحواً من قيامه ثم قال‏:‏ سمع الله لمن حمده، ربنا لك الحمد‏.
>   ثم قام قياماً طويلاً قريباً مما ركع ثم سجد فقال‏:‏ ‏"‏سبحان ربي
>   الأعلى‏"‏ فكان سجوده قريباً من قيامه
>
> Hudhaifah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: I offered Salat
>   (Tahajjud - optional night prayer) with the Prophet (ﷺ) one night, and
>   he started reciting (Surat) Al-Baqarah. I thought that he would bow at
>   the end of one hundred Verses, but he continued reciting; I, then,
>   thought that he would perhaps recite the whole (Surah) in a Rak'ah,
>   but he proceeded on, and I thought he would perhaps bow on completing
>   (this Surah); he then started (reciting Surat) An-Nisa'; he then
>   started (Surat) Al-'Imran and his recitation was unhurried. And when
>   he recited the Verses which referred to the Glory of Allah, he
>   glorified Him (by saying Subhan Allah - My Rubb, the Supreme is far
>   removed from every imperfection), the Great, and when he recited the
>   Verses that mention supplication, he supplicated, and when he recited
>   the Verses that mention seeking Refuge of the Rubb, he sought (His)
>   Refuge. Then he bowed and said: "My Rubb, the Supreme is far removed
>   from every imperfection (Subhana Rabbiyal-Azim);" his bowing lasted
>   about the same length of time as his standing (and then on returning
>   to the standing posture after Ruku') he said: "Allah listened to him
>   who praised Him (Sami' Allahu liman hamidah, Rabbana wa lakal hamd)."
>   Then he stood about the same length of time as he had spent in bowing.
>   He then prostrated himself and said: "My Rubb, the Supreme is far
>   removed from every imperfection (Subhana Rabbiyal-A'la)," and his
>   prostration lasted nearly the same length of time as his standing.

The link above does not mention the full chain, but it was narrated through multiple chains that go through:

1. Al-A'amash (الأعمش), who is Sulaiman ibn Mahran
2. Sa'ad ibn 'Ubaida (سعد بن عبيدة)
3. Aِl-Mustawrid ibn Al-Ahnaf (المستورد بن الأحنف)
4. Selatah ibn Zofar (صلة بن زفر)
5. Hudhayfah ibn al-Yaman (حذيفة بن اليمان)